# Using Windows Live Mesh with Flash Builder (Eclipse)

Tags: office-365

Any Windows Live Mesh gurus that could tell me what is not working with my setup? I have a netbook and a desktop - both with FB 4.5 (Basically Eclipse as far as I can tell) and thought it would be easier to use a service like Live Mesh or Dropbox to sync the two computers (I'll never be on both at once.. the idea is to use the netbook when I'm commuting) It seems to sync alright, but then on the next time I open, nothing is working on either system anymore.

*This may belong over in regular stackoverflow, but I couldn't decide so I guessed.

Answer (score 1):

(I was trying to sync a project, but wasn't watching where it synced to closely enough.. It was saving to my home folder instead of the project folder.)

To sync a folder to somewhere other than your home folder:

1. Select folder to sync on one computer, but do NOT select anywhere to sync to.
2. Open Live Mesh on other computer, and select the folder you just created.
3. Select where to save to.
4. Folders will now be synced.